# Create a networkx color_map from OrderedDict elements

Tags: python, dictionary, networkx, ordereddictionary

The goal is to create a networkx graph based on eigenvalue centrality and highlight the top five nodes of highest centrality measure with a different node color.

Below is my current script. It's working fine and everything's just set to one color for now.

```
#import packages 
import pandas as pd
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import collections

#read data into nx graph
G = nx.from_pandas_dataframe(df, 'col1', 'col2')

#get dictionary of centrality measures and order it
eig = nx.eigenvector_centrality(G) 
ordered = collections.OrderedDict(sorted(eig.items(), reverse = True,  key=lambda t: t[1]))

#draw graph
nx.draw_spring(G, k=1, node_color = 'skyblue', 
               node_size = 200, font_size = 6, with_labels = True)
plt.show()
```

Below is what I'm experimenting with for the node coloring. I'm attempting to append the first five ordered dictionary key names to the color_map, setting them to a different color from the rest. Please let me know if you have any suggestions here or if another method would simpler. If possible, I'd prefer to stick to the packages I'm using.

```
#adjust color of top three
color_map = []
for key, value in ordered:
    if key < 5:
        color_map.append('blue')
    else: color_map.append('green')
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a bad question, but I am pretty sure its a duplicate...Either way, I'll try to answer it. You will have to forgive me for being vague because I can't run your code and I've not tried to write an example of your problem. I will update my answer when I can run an example of your code later. However, for now I believe changing the node colour is similar to changing the edge colour. Going from that, you need to focus on the this line of your code to change the node colour;

```
#draw graph
nx.draw_spring(G, k=1, node_color = 'skyblue', 
               node_size = 200, font_size = 6, with_labels = True)
```

and this is an example of how you could do this;

```
# depending on how your graph is being read from the pandas-
# dataframe this should pull out the correct value to associate-
# the colour with
nodes = G.nodes()
# Just a list to hold all the node colours
node_colours = []
for node in nodes:
    if node < 5:
        node_colours.append('blue')
    else:
        node_colours.append('green')
#draw graph, substitute the single colour with ur list of colours
nx.draw_spring(G, k=1, node_color = node_colours, 
               node_size = 200, font_size = 6, with_labels = True)
```

I hope this helps! I will get back to it later when I test an example of this on my own machine.

-Edit-

Since the OP has answered his own question, I will not elaborate further with my example. However, if anyone is interested in my example (but if it unfortunately throws any error) and wants me to fix it and expand on it, just leave me a comment.

Tiz

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Tiz! Unfortunately the pandas data frame doesn't actually contain the centrality measures, which is what I need to sort by. I actually solved it a bit before you posted and will submit my answer. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. There's no need to create a separate OrderedDict. Applying the key=eig.get argument to sorted() allows you to sort a dictionary by value (the biggest obstacle for this problem). Then I can just filter this and apply it to cmap.